# How to build a regular expression to achieve the following output using bash?

Tags: regex, bash

Hello everyone I am processing some text I have the following list:

```
19599
9259
9259
9259
9259
9259
9159
9157
RTSR
RTSR
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
9159
```

My desired output would be:

```
019599
009259
009259
009259
009259
009259
009159
009157
RTSR
RTSR
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
009159
```

I tried manually with notepad but is too long the list, I believe that the best approach to take is to build a regular expression, the regular expression should look for the thinks that begins with a number and count how many chars have to then put two or one 0 to make the size of that number of 6, for instance

```
19599 -> 019599
9259 -> 009259
```

but it should not to do any change in the lines that begins with letters, for instance:

```
AWKJ001
```

Thanks for the support,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` can do this easily:

```
awk '$0+0 == $0 {$0 = sprintf("%06i", $0)} 1' file

019599
009259
009259
009259
009259
009259
009159
009157
RTSR
RTSR
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
009159
```

**How it works:**

- `$0+0 == $0` checks if given line is numeric only
- `sprintf("%06i", $0)` makes it `6` in length with `0` padding

Comment: Thanks for the support, this was very helpul, awk is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ple 'if (/^\d/) {$_="0" x (6-length($_)) . $_}' input
```

Output:

```
019599
009259
009259
009259
009259
009259
009159
009157
RTSR
RTSR
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
009159
```

Conceptually, this is very simple. We check if the default variable (`$_`) contains a strings that starts with a digit and if does, we just preppend `6-length($_)` zeros in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I don't have many experience with perl but it was very helpul

Answer (score 1):

Some `sed`. First replace the beginnings of all strings of numbers with five 0s (`9259` -> `000009259`) then replace all number strings with the last six number using backreferencing (<s>`000`</s>`009259`):

```
$ sed  's/^\([0-9]\+\)/00000\1/; s/^[0-9]*\([0-9]\{6,\}\)$/\1/' foo
019599
009259
009259
009259
009259
009259
009159
009157
RTSR
RTSR
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
AWKJ001
009159
```

Comment: thanks this was very helpful I believe that the best options for this specific case are awk and sed, thanks for the support,